# react inter component variable availability : redux and react query

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-query

My question is about variables availability accross elements in react when not using redux store.

Im trying to get rid of complex redux because my use case doesnt need that much complexity and trying to use react query.

Suppose i have a App.js defined like this:

```
function App() { 
const queryClient = useQueryClient()
const userQuery = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["token"],
    queryFn: () => my_api_retrieve_function,
    //onError: queryClient.invalidateQueries(["user"]),
  })

  const router = createBrowserRouter([
   {
    path: "/",
    element: <Home/>,
  },
    {
    path: "/contact",
    element: <Contact/>,
  },
]);

return (
<RouterProvider router={router} />
);
```

My App.js is a stable element included in index.js

If I declare a variable retrieved from backend in Home element and i want it to be available in Contact element, or if i want my query declared in App.js available in other elements, do i need to fetch with react query in both element with this code:

```
const queryClient = useQueryClient()
const userQuery = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["user"],
    queryFn: () => my_api_retrieve_function,
  })
  console.log(userQuery.data);
```

Is there a way to use the appropriate routing, or use next.js (in csr mode), so i only need one fetch in one element and it will be available in the other element?

I would like to fetch the data the minimum number of times possible.

I have tried to tweak staleTime and cacheTime but it doesnt answer my fundamental question.

Thanks